# Should I put a C++ macro guard in every header file?

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a little C project. Since I want it to also be included from C++ I thought about using C++ guards to make it work, like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
// code
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In my project I have some headers that *must not be included directly* from an eventual C++ file using the project. However I am facing the doubt: is putting C++ guards in that header files too a needed precaution?

Comment: If you have headers which _must not_ be included from C++, then there's no reason to place C++ guards there, and realistically there should be a preprocessor error in that file if `__cplusplus` is defined; e.g. `#error "This file should not be used with C++."`.

Comment: Header guards are only used if you include a header file in more than _one_ c++ file. Also instead of using named c++ guards you can simply use `#pragma once` on winc++.

Comment: IMHO c++ header should have different names (say hpp) so that we don't mess up with C. Moreover, if c++ mangling is not expected on some headers, I would expect the C++ user to deal with it by adding themselves the extern "C". You may wrap the C header with a hpp one adding those guards, this is mainly what is being done in c++ headers that wraps C std headers.

Comment: @Alex what do `#pragma once` would affect my code? I thought it was just a substitution for [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: What you are describing is not a "macro guard".   It is conditional compilation.   If your functions are compiled as C, then their declarations need to be specified as `extern "C"` to call them from code compiled as C++.    If all of your C code is being compiled as C++, then there is often no need for the C functions to be `extern "C"`

Comment: @Peter Strictly (and pedantically) if all the code is compiled as C++, then there are no C functions - they would be C++ functions.

Comment: @Clifford - Yes, but this question is about taking code written as C, and using it in C++.

Comment: @Peter : There is a difference between linking object code compiled as C and compiling code that is valid C using a C++ compiler.  Even if it is valid C code, if you compile it as C++, then it _is_ C++.  That was my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> must not be included directly from an eventual C++ file

Even if they are included *indirectly* via nested includes, C++ compilation will be applied and without the `extern "C"` the symbols in the C++ compiled modules will not be the same as those in the C compiled modules that you are linking to.

Apart from that it is good practice and cannot do any harm to include them for interoperability - you may not intend these headers to be used in C++ compilation now, but you cannot tell how they might be used in the future.

If you want to explicitly prevent C++ compilation being applied to a C header, a better solution would be to use:

```
#if defined __cplusplus
    #error C-only header included in C++ compilation
#endif
```

That way the issue is highlighted at compilation (or pre-processing in fact) rather then causing a linker error that may be harder to interpret when it is telling you that `xxx` is undefined when you have clearly defined it - but in a different language.

Comment: It's worth also noting that an alternative approach is to just _not_ use the `extern "C"` block in the header, and instead make the consuming C++ project wrap the `#include` statements in the `extern "C"` block